# Removing top of PriorityQueue?

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

Assume that I am using the PriorityQueue class from Java.util. I want to remove the largest number from the PriorityQueue pq, which we assume is at the head of the queue.

Will the following work?

```
// 1 
int head = pq.peek();
pq.dequeue(head);

// 2
int head = pq.dequeue(pq.peek());
```

Would this work the same for non-primitives as well?

Comment: Care to enlighten us why you don't want to use `poll()`?

Comment: Where did you find the `dequeue` method? [My API doesn't show it](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) ..?

Answer (score 11):

`Queue#peek` and `Queue#element` return the head value of the queue, `Queue#poll` and `Queue#remove` return *and remove* it.

It looks like

```
int head = pq.poll();
```

is what you want.

And: it will *only* work for non-primitive values because a queue will store objects only. The trick is, that (I guess) your queue stores `Integer` values and Java 1.5+ can automatically convert the results to `int` primitives (outboxing). So it *feels* like the queue stored `int` values.

Comment: question is to remove the largest element which is Max()

Comment: @JaydeepShil it's a priority queue. The max value is guaranteed to be at the head of the queue. That's what she explained in her question.

Comment: Slight point of clarification for other readers: The _min_ value is guaranteed to be the head of a `PriorityQueue`.  However, you can provide a comparator that inverts the natural ordering of your data, making the max look like the min and so forth (e.g., `Comparator.reverseOrder()`), presumably what OP has done.  [But from the perspective of the queue, it's the min](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html): "The _head_ of this queue is the _least_ element with respect to the specified ordering."

Answer (score 5):

`peek()` - return but doesn't remove head value

`poll()` - return and remove head value

```
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

        pq.add(2);pq.add(3);

        System.out.println(pq); // [2, 3]
        System.out.println(pq.peek()); // head 2
        System.out.println(pq); // 2 still exists. [2, 3]
        System.out.println(pq.poll()); // 2. remove head (2)
        System.out.println(pq); // [3]
```