# Error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, casting, priority-queue

I am getting the following error for the given code.

I am not able to rectify what is the error?

In the line: "Long pw1 = pq1.remove();"

```
    int n = in.ni();
    long a[] = in.gla(n);
    PriorityQueue<Long> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
    Map<Long, PriorityQueue> map = new HashMap<>();
    Set<Long> s = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (s.contains(a[i])) {
            map.get(a[i]).add(i);
        } else {
            pq.add(a[i]);
            s.add(a[i]);
            map.put(a[i], new PriorityQueue<>());
            map.get(a[i]).add(i);
        }
    }
    while(!pq.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println(pq.remove());
    }
    while(!pq.isEmpty()){
        long p = pq.remove();
        System.out.println(p);
        PriorityQueue<Long> pq1 = map.get(p);
        while(pq1.size()>1){
            Long pw1 = pq1.remove();
            Long pw = pq1.remove();
            System.out.println(pw);
            if(s.contains(2*p)){
                map.get(2*p).add(1);
            }
            else{
                s.add(2*p);
                pq.add(2*p);
                map.put(p*2, new PriorityQueue<Long>());
                map.get(2*p).add(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Comment: Do you want to remove the top of the priority queue, and then store the (removed) top to the variable `pw1`? Please make it clear what you want.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488325/removing-top-of-priorityqueue)?

Comment: Yes i want  to remove the top of the priority queue and then store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decflaration of `map`'s value is the [*raw type*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) `PriorityQueue` (rather than the *paramaterized type* `PriorityQueue<Long>`). Give it a type by changing

```
Map<Long, PriorityQueue> map = new HashMap<>();
```

to:

```
Map<Long, PriorityQueue<Long>> map = new HashMap<>();
```